# Why is my second mdc-textfield label attaching to my first mdc-textfield?

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5, material-components

I am working with a Laravel view using MDC-Web (Material Design Components Web), and am having some problems with labels not attaching to their respective inputs correctly.

```
  <section class="mdc-card__supporting-text" style="flex-direction: row">

      <div class="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">
        <input id="lang" required onkeyup="return forceLower(this)"
          type="text" class="mdc-textfield__input"
          value="{{ $fontmap->lang }}"  aria-controls="lang-helptext">
        <label class="mdc-textfield__label mdc-textfield__label--float-above" for="lang">
          Language
        </label>
        <div class="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
      </div>
      <p id="lang-helptext" class="mdc-textfield-helptext" aria-hidden="true">
        Please use lowercase name for language.
        @if ($errors->has('lang'))
          <span style="color: red">
            {{ $errors->first('lang') }}
          </span>
        @endif
      </p>

      <div class="mdc-textfield" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield">
        <input id="short" required type="text" onkeyup="return forceLower(this)"
          maxlength="2" size="2" class="mdc-textfield__input"
          value="{{ $fontmap->short }}"  aria-controls="short-helptext">
          <label class="mdc-textfield__label mdc-textfield__label--float-above" for="short">
            Short
          </label>
        <div class="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
      </div>
      <p id="short-helptext" class="mdc-textfield-helptext" aria-hidden="true">
        Please type in the two character lowercase ISO code for the langauge.
        <a href="https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php" target="_blank">
          ISO 639-1 Chart
        </a>
        @if ($errors->has('short'))
          <span style="color: red">
            {{ $errors->first('short') }}
          </span>
        @endif
      </p>
```

With my JavaScript looking like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  mdc.autoInit();
  mdc.textfield.MDCTextfield.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-textfield'));
  function forceLower(strInput) {
    return strInput.value = strInput.value.toLowerCase();
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that the second 'short' mdc-textfield attached to the bottom of the 'lang' mdc-textfield. I would like for the labels to attach to their correct inputs, but I do not see where and why I have a problem.

[image: mdc-textfield attaching wrong]

None of my other mdc-textfield layouts have this problem (I have several multi field mdc-textfield layouts that work fine). I suspect the error is small and subtle, but can't find it after looking at the code.

Does it have anything to do with my additonal force lowercase javascript function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by rewriting the mdc-textfields again, from scratch with the resulting code being:

```
<section class="mdc-card__supporting-text" style="flex-direction: row">

  @if ($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
          </ul>
      </div>
  @endif

  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    <div class="mdc-textfield mdc-textfield--upgraded" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield" style="width: 100%">
      <input type="text" id="lang" name="lang" class="mdc-textfield__input" value="{{ $fontmap->lang }}"
      required onkeyup="return forceLower(this)" aria-controls="lang-helptext">
      <label class="mdc-textfield__label mdc-textfield__label--float-above" for="lang">
        Language Name
      </label>
      <div class="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="lang-helptext" class="mdc-textfield-helptext" aria-hidden="true">
      Please user lowercase name.
      @if ($errors->has('lang'))
        <span style="color: red">
          {{ $errors->first('lang') }}
        </span>
      @endif
    </p>

    <div class="mdc-textfield mdc-textfield--upgraded" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextfield" style="width: 100%">
      <input type="text" id="short" name="short" class="mdc-textfield__input" value="{{ $fontmap->short }}"
      required onkeyup="return forceLower(this)" aria-controls="short-helptext">
      <label class="mdc-textfield__label mdc-textfield__label--float-above" for="short">
        Code
      </label>
      <div class="mdc-textfield__bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
    <p id="short-helptext" class="mdc-textfield-helptext" aria-hidden="true">
      Please type in the two character lowercase ISO code for the langauge.
      <a href="https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php" target="_blank">
        ISO 639-1 Chart
      </a>
      @if ($errors->has('short'))
        <span style="color: red">
          {{ $errors->first('short') }}
        </span>
      @endif
    </p>
```

I do not actually see why it should be different. No changes to the JavaScript did anything. I think it may possibly be the order of the attributes for the input, but I can not confirm that, if not some minor detail I just haven't caught yet. Any additional answers providing the explanation of why it didn't work initially are appreciated. Thanks!